# The android webview can not play the video when I change the src at run time

Tags: android, jquery, video, webview

I have a simple video tag like

```
<video id="video_html" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And I add the url at run time

```
$("#video_html").attr('src','...a.mp4');
```

It can not play on the android webview (4.1.2) , so I input all the `<video>...</video>` code at run time. However this time the auto play is not working(it does not play automatically but only when I press on it), how to fix it? I wonder what is the jquery code to add the url in video tag in run time for the android webview? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for autoplay to work without a user gesture, please toggle this WebSetting: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)

Comment: yes. The option is introduce after API level 17 . It just makes developer confusing and check whether the problem is cause by javascript/ html . Thanks for your help